# Show that the recursive sequence converges and find its limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $x_1>2$ and $x_{n+1} := 1 + \sqrt{x_n - 1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $\{x_n\}$ is decreasing and bounded below, and find its limit.

I showed that it's bounded below ($x_n>2$ for all $n$) using induction. But then I don't know how to do the rest. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Rewrite this as a recursion over $y_n=x_n-1$.

Comment: Is $x_1>1$?????

Comment: Sorry, it's $x_1 >2$

Comment: Whenever they say "show the the sequences converges and find its limit" they really mean "find its limit and then show that the sequence converges".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $x_1 \ge 2, x_{n+1}=1+\sqrt{x_n-1}$. Find the limit, if it is convergent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264019/let-x-1-ge-2-x-n1-1-sqrtx-n-1-find-the-limit-if-it-is-convergent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any recursively defined sequence where the recursive relation (in this case $1+\sqrt{x_n - 1}$) is *continuous* can only ever converge to $x$ which are *stationary points*, i.e. points so that if you enter $x$ into the relation, you get $x$ back.

This means that *if* your sequence converges to some $x$, then it must be the case that $$x=1+\sqrt{x-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Clearly
$$
x_{n+1}-1=\sqrt{x_n-1}=\sqrt[4]{x_{n-1}-1}=\cdots=(x_1-1)^{2^{-n}}\to 1,
$$
and hence
$$
x_n\to 2.
$$

Answer (score 1):

If you already prove that $x_n> 2$, then  $$\dfrac{x_{n+1}-1}{x_n -1} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_n -1}} < 1 $$
$$\implies x_{n+1} -1 < x_n -1$$
So $x_n$ is decreasing and bounded below. The limit point is already in the other answers.